# Macro to create a text file with values from cells and text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Im trying to create a macro in excel that creates a text file which some of the parameters are on excel cells.

The output would be for example:

The kid is **'cell (1,1)'** old.

His name is **'cell (1,2)'**.

I managed already to create the file but Im straggling to add the variable in the middle of the text.
Follow bellow the code that I have written:

```
Sub Generate_KML()

Dim strPath                            As String
Dim iFileNumber                        As Long
Dim strHeader                          As String
Dim strData                            As String

strPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
"KML File (*.kml), *.kml", Title:="Save Location")

iFileNumber = FreeFile()
strHeader = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
strData = "Test 2"

Open strPath For Output As #iFileNumber
Print #iFileNumber, strHeader
Print #iFileNumber, strData

Close #iFileNumber
End Sub
```

Thank you!
Regards,
Richard Lima

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you're struggling?

```
strdata = "The kid is " & cells(1,1).value & "His name is " cells(1,2).value
```

You pretty much have it down, just use `&` to concatenate.

If you're struggling with the print, [see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/387192/excel-create-text-file-named-after-a-cell-containing-other-cell-data) for examples.