# Make a text file from Excel using first colum as name input

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've tried to make my first VBA macro.

It gives me an error when trying to run it, why?

Any one able to fix it so it works (that is first use first column as text name and all the other as text in the file, and it the next column, row has the same name as the previous I want it to write that row to the same text file, but one row down)

Example

```
Colum1      Coulum2

object1      value1

object2      value2

object3      value3

object3      value4

object4      value5
```

Text file 1 object1.txt inside file

value 1

Text file 2 object2.txt inside file

value 2

Text file 3 object3.txt inside file

value 3

value 4 ("still same file")

Text file 4 object4.txt inside file

value 5

Code:

```
Sub CreateFile()
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
        MyFile = ActiveCell.Value & ".txt"
        'set and open file for output
        fnum = FreeFile()
        Open MyFile For Output As fnum
        'use Print when you want the string without quotation marks
        n = 0
        If ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(0 - 1, 1).Select Then
            Close #fnum
            Return
        Else: ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
            Print #fnum, ActiveCell.Offset(n, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(n, 2)
            n = n + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Loop without do, but i think it might be more problems then that? I do think to be solved one needs to make a Excel file with the data above and try.

Comment: You are missing an `End if`. Side note: you want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: To help with debugging you should try stepping through the application and seeing where it fails. I'm not sure if Excel includes it, but you could try enabling code hinting to help catch your syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateFileEachLine()

    Dim myPathTo As String
    myPathTo = "C:\usr...."
    Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
    Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim fileOut As Object
    Dim myFileName As String

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    Do While i < lastRow
        myFileName = myPathTo & ActiveCell.Value & ".txt"
        Set fileOut = myFileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(myFileName)
        Do While (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        fileOut.write ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    fileOut.Close
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Help from: [Excel - Create text file named after a cell containing other cell data](https://superuser.com/questions/387192/excel-create-text-file-named-after-a-cell-containing-other-cell-data)

Comment: However now i have an other problem how to i make ´the text to write to a new line in the same document while looping?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
Sub CreateFile()
    Close #fnum
    Close MyFile
    myPathTo = "C:\Users\tianr\Downloads\Ny mapp\"


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    Do While i < lastRow
        MyFile = myPathTo & ActiveCell.Value & ".txt"
        fnum = FreeFile()
        Open MyFile For Output As fnum
        Do While (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        Print #fnum, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) & " ; "
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Close #fnum
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```